# In app purchase, testing using sandbox

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Can I still test in app purchase using sandbox with the following warning?

> Note: You do not currently have a iOS Paid Apps contract in effect. If
>   this In-App Purchase was submitted with your app, then your app will
>   not be available on the App Store until your contract goes into
>   effect. Legal, Admin, and Finance users can go to the Contracts, Tax,
>   and Banking module in iTunes Connect to view your contract status.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When adding and testing in-app purchase in your application you have to have a contract for paid application and provide your contact info , bank info, and tax info.

It's not possible to test without it.